# Do I use integer or float?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, floating-point, integer, google-cloud-datastore

This is the model in Google App Engine:

```
class Rep(db.Model):
    mAUTHOR = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)
    mUNIQUE = db.StringProperty()
    mCOUNT = db.IntegerProperty()
    mDATE = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    mDATE0 = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    mWEIGHT = db.FloatProperty()
```

So, `mCOUNT` is integer and `mWEIGHT` is float. I calculate the age of the item like this:

```
    age1 = datetime.datetime.now() - rep.mDATE0
    age_hour = float(age1.seconds) / 3600
    rep.mWEIGHT = float((rep.mCOUNT - 1) / (age_hour + 2)**1.5)
```

But when I try a query like this:

```
QUERY = Rep.all()
QUERY.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
QUERY.order("-mWEIGHT")
RESULTS = QUERY.fetch(10)    

for result in RESULTS:
    self.response.out.write("mUNIQUE: <b>%s</b> | "
                                "mWEIGHT: %f | "  
                                "mCOUNT: %s | <br />"  
                             % (result.mUNIQUE, 
                                result.mWEIGHT,
                                # line 103                               
                                result.mCOUNT,
                                ))
```

I get a `TypeError` on line 103 which is

```
result.mCOUNT,
TypeError: a float is required
```

Why would mCOUNT be float? By the way, the error is raised only if the item is not in the datastore and it is written for the first time by the `else` clause of the `if loop`.

Can you help me use the correct type? Thanks for your help.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that I had `%f` for string formatting for `mWEIGHT` and changing that to `%s` seems to solve the problem (but I don't know why. Is it because `mWEIGHT=None`?):

```
for result in RESULTS:
    self.response.out.write("mUNIQUE: <b>%s</b> | "
                          # changing %f to %s appears to solve the problem.
                            "mWEIGHT: %f | "  
                            "mCOUNT: %s | <br />"  
                         % (result.mUNIQUE, 
                            result.mWEIGHT if result.mWEIGHT is not None else 0.0,
                            result.mWEIGHT,                                           
                            result.mCOUNT,
                                    ))
```

And here are some values:

```
mUNIQUE: A | mWEIGHT: 0.299954933969 | mCOUNT: 2 | 
mUNIQUE: Z | mWEIGHT: 0.0 | mCOUNT: 1 | # With answer by TokenMacGuy 
mUNIQUE: R | mWEIGHT: None | mCOUNT: 1 | # with %f changed to %s 
mUNIQUE: P | mWEIGHT: None | mCOUNT: 1 | # with %f changed to %s
```

Any suggestions how I can add `rep.mWEIGHT` to the `else` clause?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The entire code is below:

```
    K = []
    s = self.request.get('sentence')           
    K.append(s)                              
    K = f2.remove_empty(K[0].split('\r\n'))     
    UNIQUES = f2.f2(K)
    COUNTS = f2.lcount(K, UNIQUES)    

    C_RESULT = "no results yet"         

    for i in range(len(UNIQUES)):                        
        C_QUERY = Rep.all()
        C_QUERY.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
        C_QUERY.filter("mUNIQUE =", UNIQUES[i])
        C_RESULT = C_QUERY.fetch(1)                
        if C_RESULT:
            rep = C_RESULT[0]
            rep.mCOUNT+=COUNTS[i]
            age1 = datetime.datetime.now() - rep.mDATE0
            age_hour = float(age1.seconds) / 3600
            rep.mWEIGHT = float((rep.mCOUNT - 1) / (age_hour + 2)**1.5)

            self.response.out.write("<b>rep.UNIQUE: %s</b>: <br />"
            #                        "rep.mCOUNT: %s <br />" 
                                     "rep.mWEIGHT: %s <br />"
            #                        "C_RESULT: %s <br />"
            #                        "rep: %s <br />"
            #                        "utc_tuple: %s <br />"
            #                        "mDATE0_epoch: %s <br />"
                                     "rep.mDATE0: %s "
                                     "age_hour: %s <br />"
            #                        
                                  % (rep.mUNIQUE,
            #                        rep.mCOUNT, 
                                     rep.mWEIGHT,
            #                        C_RESULT,
            #                        rep,
            #                        utc_tuple,
            #                        mDATE0_epoch,
                                     rep.mDATE0,
                                     age_hour,                        
                                    ))                     
            rep.put()
        else:
            rep = Rep()
            rep.mCOUNT = COUNTS[i]
            rep.mUNIQUE = UNIQUES[i]

            rep.put()        

            self.response.out.write("<b>rep.UNIQUE: %s</b>: |"
                                    "rep.mCOUNT: %s: <br />"
                                 % (rep.mUNIQUE,
                                    rep.mCOUNT,))

    QUERY = Rep.all()
    QUERY.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
    QUERY.order("-mWEIGHT")
    RESULTS = QUERY.fetch(10)    

    for result in RESULTS:
        self.response.out.write("mUNIQUE: <b>%s</b> | "
                                "mWEIGHT: %f | "  
                                "mCOUNT: %s | <br />"  
                             % (result.mUNIQUE, 
                                result.mWEIGHT,  
                                result.mCOUNT,
                                ))
```

Comment: What are the type and value of result.mWeight in the last string interpolation where the exception is raised ?

Comment: Try just casting it as a float. `float(rep.mCount)`.

Comment: @Falmarri: I just tried this; but it did not work. I got the same error. Thanks.

Comment: @Luper Rouch: How do I get the type and value of mWEIGHT? When I try I get the error message? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Luper Rouch: I added some values as edits above.

Comment: Please don't just tell us what error you got - actually include the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are occasionally *not* setting `mWEIGHT`.  How about changing

```
for result in RESULTS:
        self.response.out.write("mUNIQUE: <b>%s</b> | "
                                "mWEIGHT: %f | "  
                                "mCOUNT: %s | <br />"  
                             % (result.mUNIQUE, 
                                result.mWEIGHT,  
                                result.mCOUNT,
                                ))
```

to

```
for result in RESULTS:
        self.response.out.write("mUNIQUE: <b>%s</b> | "
                                "mWEIGHT: %f | "  
                                "mCOUNT: %s | <br />"  
                             % (result.mUNIQUE, 
                                result.mWEIGHT if result.mWEIGHT is not None else 0.0,  
                                result.mCOUNT,
                                ))
```

Comment: TokenMacGuy: I just tried your answer and it works! Thanks for your help. Can you give some more clues why actually `mCOUNT` was throwing the error? And how can I fix the code so that I don't have to patch the iteration? Thanks again?

Comment: you have a multi line expression.  Actually getting the right line for that is not so easy.  In particular, errors often occur on the line before the reported error.

Comment: `blah if blah is not None else 0.0` can be more succinctly written as `blah or 0.0`.